# How to get rid of pytz UnknownTimeZoneError in my Django logs?

Tags: python, django, apache, pytz

I've deployed a Django Application on Windows Server 2022 and error logs are flooded with the following message:

```
pytz.exceptions.UnknownTimeZoneError: 'Europe/Paris'\r, referer: https://my_server_url
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred
```

I've checked my pytz installation and it seems to work just fine :

```
# run Windows cmd as Apache service account
python manage.py shell
from django.conf import settings
import pytz
pytz.timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE)
<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Paris' LMT+0:09:00 STD>
settings.TIME_ZONE in pytz.all_timezones
True
```

I've tried to uninstall and reinstall my virtual environnement and upgrade/downgrade pytz, without success.

I've no idea on how to investigate this problem furthermore and how to solve it.

Here is the application setup :

```
Apache 2.4.52 (built from sources)
Python 3.10.4
Mod_wsgi 4.9.0
Django 3.2.9
pytz 2021.3
```

#### Edit 1.

Here are the relevant Django settings (I mostly use defaults):

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris'
USE_TZ = False
USE_L10N = False # also tried with True, same error
```

#### Edit 2.

Here is the full error traceback.

```
 # when any exception is raised in the app
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\r, referer: https://my_server_url
 \r, referer: https://my_server_url
 Traceback (most recent call last):\r, referer: https://my_server_url
   File "path_to_venv\\django\\core\\handlers\\exception.py", line 47, in inner\r, referer: https://my_server_url
     response = get_response(request)\r, referer: https://my_server_url
   File "path_to_venv\\django\\utils\\deprecation.py", line 117, in __call__\r, referer: https://my_server_url
     response = response or self.get_response(request)\r, referer: https://my_server_url
   File "path_to_venv\\django\\core\\handlers\\exception.py", line 49, in inner\r, referer: https://my_server_url
     response = response_for_exception(request, exc)\r, referer: https://my_server_url
   File "path_to_venv\\django\\core\\handlers\\exception.py", line 115, in response_for_exception\r, referer: https://my_server_url
     log_response(\r, referer: https://my_server_url
   File "path_to_venv\\django\\utils\\log.py", line 224, in log_response\r, referer: https://my_server_url
     getattr(logger, level)(\r, referer: https://my_server_url
   File "C:\\Program Files\\Python3.10\\Lib\\logging\\__init__.py", line 1497, in error\r, referer: https://my_server_url
     self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)\r, referer: https://my_server_url
   File "C:\\Program Files\\Python3.10\\Lib\\logging\\__init__.py", line 1615, in _log\r, referer: https://my_server_url
     self.handle(record)\r, referer: https://my_server_url
   File "C:\\Program Files\\Python3.10\\Lib\\logging\\__init__.py", line 1625, in handle\r, referer: https://my_server_url
     self.callHandlers(record)\r, referer: https://my_server_url
   File "C:\\Program Files\\Python3.10\\Lib\\logging\\__init__.py", line 1687, in callHandlers\r, referer: https://my_server_url
     hdlr.handle(record)\r, referer: https://my_server_url
   File "C:\\Program Files\\Python3.10\\Lib\\logging\\__init__.py", line 967, in handle\r, referer: https://my_server_url
     self.emit(record)\r, referer: https://my_server_url
   File "path_to_venv\\django\\utils\\log.py", line 120, in emit\r, referer: https://my_server_url
     message = "%s\\n\\n%s" % (self.format(no_exc_record), reporter.get_traceback_text())\r, referer: https://my_server_url
   File "path_to_venv\\django\\views\\debug.py", line 353, in get_traceback_text\r, referer: https://my_server_url
     return t.render(c)\r, referer: https://my_server_url
   File "path_to_venv\\django\\template\\base.py", line 170, in render\r, referer: https://my_server_url
     return self._render(context)\r, referer: https://my_server_url
   File "path_to_venv\\django\\template\\base.py", line 162, in _render\r, referer: https://my_server_url
     return self.nodelist.render(context)\r, referer: https://my_server_url
   File "path_to_venv\\django\\template\\base.py", line 938, in render\r, referer: https://my_server_url
     bit = node.render_annotated(context)\r, referer: https://my_server_url
   File "path_to_venv\\django\\template\\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated\r, referer: https://my_server_url
     return self.render(context)\r, referer: https://my_server_url
   File "path_to_venv\\django\\template\\base.py", line 988, in render\r, referer: https://my_server_url
     output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)\r, referer: https://my_server_url
   File "path_to_venv\\django\\template\\base.py", line 698, in resolve\r, referer: https://my_server_url
     new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)\r, referer: https://my_server_url
   File "path_to_venv\\django\\template\\defaultfilters.py", line 717, in date\r, referer: https://my_server_url
     return formats.date_format(value, arg)\r, referer: https://my_server_url
   File "path_to_venv\\django\\utils\\formats.py", line 152, in date_format\r, referer: https://my_server_url
     return dateformat.format(value, get_format(format or 'DATE_FORMAT', use_l10n=use_l10n))\r, referer: https://my_server_url
   File "path_to_venv\\django\\utils\\dateformat.py", line 326, in format\r, referer: https://my_server_url
     df = DateFormat(value)\r, referer: https://my_server_url
   File "path_to_venv\\django\\utils\\dateformat.py", line 59, in __init__\r, referer: https://my_server_url
     self.timezone = get_default_timezone()\r, referer: https://my_server_url
   File "path_to_venv\\django\\utils\\timezone.py", line 52, in get_default_timezone\r, referer: https://my_server_url
     return pytz.timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE)\r, referer: https://my_server_url
   File "path_to_venv\\pytz\\__init__.py", line 188, in timezone\r, referer: https://my_server_url
     raise UnknownTimeZoneError(zone)\r, referer: https://my_server_url
```

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace of the exception please?

Comment: @DMalan I've added the full traceback, see edit 2.

Comment: Have you tried setting it to some other timezone to check if that works?

Comment: Yes I have tried with several timezones, including default one.

Answer (score 1):

Django 4 disables time zones by default. According to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/timezones/), you should set USE_TZ to True to enable it. Django 5 will enable it by default.
See also [USE_TZ](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std-setting-USE_TZ) for more info about this setting and links to related settings.

Comment: I'm running Django 3 and  already tried enabling/disabling USE_TZ

Comment: thank you for adding information to your question. i could not read that you used django 3 and i only read that you altered USE_L10N which changes text formatting around dates but does not enable or disable timezones.

Answer (score 0):

You are using linux timezone format on Windows server. Here is [mapping](https://gist.github.com/alejzeis/ad5827eb14b5c22109ba652a1a267af5)